Supabase, Nextjs14 and sessions process
I developed a web application with Nextjs 14 and react that uses Supabase for user management and authorizations. On the other hand, I have developed a Google Forms addon that manages to store the id of a form in my database although I'm not sure if this process is correct. I have two questions.
The first one would be to know if the way I have programmed the process for saving the user from the GForms addon is correct. The process is as follows:

Initially, when opening the Google addon, a POST is sent to the application's API from the Google server (not client) to create a user.

In the application's API, the user is generated by calling the function:
const {data, error} = await supabase.signInwithemail({email, password});

If it exists, it returns the user's data; if not (as it is the first time), the user is created and also returns user metadata such as access_token and refresh_token. This way I know if the user existed. From that information, I get the user id and can save the form id in the database.


Is this approach correct?
The second question is that once the user is registered in the system, I want a button to appear in the addon that redirects the logged-in user to the application, and this is where I am stuck. How can I do it?

For authentication management, I use sessions created in Supabase from the server.

Two cookies are automatically generated containing all the relevant information to be able to enter, but I think it could be programmed from the Google Forms addon but I'm not sure if it would be the best option.


How could I approach this situation, would you do it differently?
Currently, the button redirects to the application login page and the user must log in.

Hey Nacho,
Auth team here - thanks for the query. I'm not too familiar with Google Forms but you'd indeed be able to obtain an access token if you have signInwithemail wrap the library methods signUp and signInWithPassword.
With respect to redirects, do you mind elaborating more on the existing setup? (e.g. do you currently have an existing button that redirects to the application login page but you'd like to redirect it to the another application page?)
If you have snippets or a diagram it would be very helpful!
